# How to automatically categorise data in panda dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe, data-binding, categorization

I have a data frame with more than 1000 rows and 200 columns something like this:

```
     my_data:
             ID,   f1,   f2, ..     ,f200   Target
             x1     3     0, ..     ,2      0
             x2     6     2, ..     ,1      1
             x3     5     4, ..     ,0      0
             x4     0     5, ..     ,18     1
             ..     .     ., ..     ,..     .
             xn     13    0, ..     ,4      0
```

First,  I want to automatically discretize these features (f1-f200) into four groups as `no`, `low`, `medium` and `high`, so that the Ids which have zero in their columns (e.g., x1 in f2 contains 0, the same in xn .. ) should be labels "no", the rest should be categorized into low, medium and high.

I found this:

```
  pd.cut(my_data,3, labels=["low", "medium", "high"])
```

But, this does not solve the problem. Any idea?

Comment: So, you mean all zeroes to be replaced by `No` and then x4 f200 be like `High` etc. ? So, all df should be converted to these 4 categories ?

Comment: Yes, the value of x4 f200 (which is 18) is high in that column, but there could be another column (e.g., f2) which 11 should be high, I mean the categorisation should be implemented based on the values in each column.

Comment: @Spedo what are the criteria for something being marked `low`, `medium` or `high`? What are the cut-off points? If you have these, then either `df.apply` can be used to check the columns for each one and then apply a category to each row.

Comment: Thats the point! since the range of each column differ from each other, and there are several features we can not decide the cut point and it should be automatically decided.

Comment: @Spedo just saw your latest comment. You will still need to set some criteria. EG in a range of a=0, z=26, is low 0%-33% or the lowest x values?

Comment: @Spedo: Check the answer..let me know if this works for you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you need to create dynamic bins and iterate columns to get this. This can be done by below:

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame()
for name,value in df1.iteritems(): ##df1 is your dataframe
    bins = [-np.inf, 0,df1[name].min()+1,df1[name].mean(), df1[name].max()]
    new_df[name] = pd.cut(df1[name], bins=bins, include_lowest=False, labels=['no','low', 'mid', 'high'])
```

Comment: Updated the code if you want to create new df with these values

Answer (score 0):

Using np.select

```
# Iterate over the Dataframe Columns i.e. f1-f200

    for col in df.columns:

        # Define your Condition
        conditions = [
            (df[col] == 0),
            (df[col] == 1),
            (df[col] == 2),
            (df[col] > 3)]

        # Values you want to map
        choices = ['no','Low', 'Medium', 'High']

        df[col] = np.select(conditions, choices, default='Any-value')
```

Comment: `0` should be named as `No` and not `Low`

Comment: @RahulAgarwal - Check now, Updated my Answer

Comment: your df only accomodates values from 0 to 3 what if one of the values is `18`. which is their in OP question

Comment: @RahulAgarwal - This solution is for Categorization, it doesn't matter with the varied and diversified data in the column, it will work for any range.

Comment: `df=pd.DataFrame({'Target':[0,1,0,3,1,2,1,0,17,1,2,0,18]})` fails here!!

Comment: it will fail because your range of data is more than the labelled defined, it has to match with the data range. Add two more labels in the renamed_categories and it will work.

Comment: Yes...but this is not what OP wants

Comment: He said Zero and rest as Low,Medium and High and that's the solution I gave. Nowhere he mentioned it will exceed above Low, Medium and High.

Comment: Just see all his columns `f1` ...`f200` and try your solution

Comment: Got it, Unclear Explanation of the Question. Nowehere he said that the range in columns are not unknown. he is referring Low, Medium, High.

Comment: Yes..that is the problem here..there is no range at all!!