# Converting target dataset into a classification dataset – Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to convert the dataset into a classification dataset by:

- Step 1: Split the range of target values into three equal parts - low, mid, and high.
- Step 2: Reassign the target values into into three categorical values 0, 1, and 2, representing low, mid and high range of values, respectively.

I tried different approach by using the method that were suggesting in this post: [How to automatically categorise data in panda dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56218439/how-to-automatically-categorise-data-in-panda-dataframe) and didn't get the result I wanted. Any suggestion?

Dataset in question:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
data = load_boston()
X = data.data
y = data.target
```

Answer (score 0):

let's find the lowest and give him the highest value (100) than the max(y) (50 in your example), we repeat this until we have done this for at 33% of your y, and we repeat this 2 times with another different value higher than max(y).
Then we use a function to modify your 100,200 and 300 to 0,1,2

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
data = load_boston()
X = data.data
y = data.target
y = list(y)
print(y)
for i in range(len(y)):
    index = y.index(min(y))
    if i < len(y)/3:
        y[index]=100
    elif i > len(y)/3 and i < 2*(len(y)/3):
        y[index]=200
    else:
        y[index]=300

def split_in_3(y):
    if y == 100:
        return 0
    elif y == 200:
        return 1
    else:
        return 2

y2 = map(split_in_3,y)

print(list(y2))
```